# how to get the current countdwon time in call back in CountDown.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-countdown

So I am using countDown.js plugin to show the next call schedule .

I would like to make poup on 5 minutes before , 2 minutes before and 1 sec before the endTime.

For now I can show popup only 1 second before the End Time , My code is as follow.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                var austDay = new Date(<?php echo strtotime(Date::Add($next_scheduled_call->next_call_time))*1000; ?>);
                $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay,onExpiry: callDue});
            });

            function  callDue(){
                @if($isSalesManagerGroup ==  'no')
                    alert('Your Call is Get to Due , Please Update Soon.');
                    location.href= "{{ URL::to('/home/leads/history/'.$next_scheduled_call->leads_id.'')}}";
                @endif    
            }
        </script>
```

How can I modify this code to get the above requirement

Answer (score 0):

With some `Date` function and with the help of `setTimeout` you can achieve this as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var austDay = new Date(<?php echo strtotime(Date::Add($next_scheduled_call->next_call_time))*1000; ?>);
        var currentDate = new Date(); //current Date
        var diff_in_sec = (austDay.getTime() - currentDate.getTime())/ 1000;

        var Seconds_Between_Dates = Math.ceil(diff_in_sec);

        var timeBefore5Min = Seconds_Between_Dates - (5 * 60);
        var timeBefore2Min = Seconds_Between_Dates - (2 * 60);

        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay,onExpiry: callDue});

        setTimeout(function(){
            callDue(); //calling function before 5 min
        },timeBefore5Min * 1000);

        setTimeout(function(){
            callDue(); //calling function before 2 min
        },timeBefore2Min * 1000);
    });

    function  callDue(){
        @if($isSalesManagerGroup ==  'no')
            alert('Your Call is Get to Due , Please Update Soon.');
            location.href= "{{ URL::to('/home/leads/history/'.$next_scheduled_call->leads_id.'')}}";
        @endif    
    }
</script>
```